# jQuery/JavaScript - Displaying value from text-input in <span>-placeholders

Tags: javascript, jquery

### I FORMULATED MY SELF VERY BADLY!

I will start over :) I appreciate your good answers, and if you can, try answering this: ( I will try to be more specific this time)

What I want is, that a `<form>`element onsubmit, onclick of a button or whatever takes the value of an `<input type="text" value="Default value">` and inserts it in a couple of `<span>`elements, I like to call "placeholders". This sample might explain it a little better:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$("input[type=button]").click(function //click the button
{ do_the_magic_thing() //make the value from id="txt_inp" appear in class="placeholder"
}); 
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="POST" action="" id="theForm"> //could also be get, I don't care
<input type="text" id="txt_inp" value="Default Value" onfocus="if (this.value == Default Value) this.value=''"> //this SHOULD make the Default Value dissapear on focus
<input type="button"> //could also be a submit

<span class="placeholder"></span> //$("#txt_inp").value; goes here
<span class="placeholder"></span> //$("#txt_inp").value; goes here
</body>
```

Now, is it really as simple as this?:

```
var do_the_magic_thing = function() {
$(".placeholder").html = $("#txt_inp").value;
};
```

I'm going to bed now - it's late in Denmark :) I will answer your comments tomorrow :)

### OLD POST:

<strike>I am **very** new to this jQuery thing, but I do understand the basics and all. Let's simplify and say I have a form which looks like this:</strike>

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" value="Default value">
<input type="submit" value="Click me">
<input type="hidden"> //hidden is for being able to submit by hitting enter
</form>
```

I've tried with `$.post`, but I just cannot get it right; it's not working for me.

Now, I would like to cancel the submit (can't that be done by just adding a `return false;` in the function returning the value, if a such is present?), but this is not crucial.

I think I typed in something like

`$.post("test.php", function(data) {

alert("This is the data submitted (and cancelled):" + data);

}); //I have also tried without the "test.php", that's not it`

Can you tell me, what I'm doing wrong please? :)

### NOTE

**It is not necessary, that the submit is cancelled, but I would like that

Nor is it necessary, that POST is the method used, but once again, this is what I prefer**

Comment: You want to intercept the form posting and see the values to be posted?

Comment: Do you mean you want to return false when the button is clicked so you can submit with XHR? Or do you mean you maybe want to do some validation and choose not to submit the form at all for one reason or another?

Comment: @Jage, I simply want to do nothing to it but retrieving the value specified in the text-input. Like if it was a "button" instead of a "submit". Is it possible to do this kind of thing with a "button" instead of a "submit"? @Ken Redler, exactly and then I want the value to be displayed in some "placeholders", for example some <span>s

Comment: Based on the text of your alert, it looks like you are misunderstanding what the data variable is.  That is the data returned from the post, not the data submitted.

Comment: In that case, I surely have! I want the data to be exactly what I typed in the text-input in the first place :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the revised version of your question, yes, it really is that simple, although the correct syntax for your "do the magic thing" function is the following:

```
var do_the_magic_thing = function() {
    $('.placeholder').html($('#txt_inp').val());
};
```

P.S. Don't worry too much about not expressing yourself, your English is much better than my Danish.

Comment: Btw, I love your site (meadmiracle.com). Masterpiece :)

Answer (score 2):

Change the id of your form to "myform" or whatever and the name of your text input to "myinput", and try something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').submit(submitMyForm);
})

function submitMyForm(e) {
    var data = new Object();
    data.whatever = $('#myinput').val();

    var post = new Object();
    //here I use a jquery json extension...you can use anything you like
    post.data = $.toJSON(data);

    $.post("test.php", post, function(returnval) {
        alert(returnval);
    }, "text");

    //this is to stop the normal form submit action
    return false;
}
```

Then in your test.php you can access it by calling $_POST['data'] (we specified this when we created the property of the "post" object called "data" like this: post.data = 'whatever'.

Comment: Okay. Great response, but what is the "e"-parameter in the function submitMyForm(e)-line?

Comment: In javascript (and thus jQuery), when you attach a callback function to an event (in this case, the "submit" event) it always passes an event object to that function. I call it "e", but you can call it anything you like (e.g. "event"). If you wanted to do something a little more custom, you could make the callback an anonymous function like this: $('#myForm').submit(function(e) {submitMyForm()};. Then, since you can run any code you like inside that anonymous function, you can call the "submitMyForm" function without any parameters...or with as many as you like.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is something like this:

```
<fieldset id="myData">
    <legend>My Data</legend>
</fieldset>

<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" value="Default value">
    <input type="submit" value="Click me">
    <input type="hidden"> //hidden is for being able to submit by hitting enter
</form>

$(function() {
   $('#myForm').submit(function() {
      //do whatever you want here.
      //this will take place after the form is submitted, but before your ajax request
      $('input[type=text]').each(function() {
          $('#myData').append('<div class="placeholder">' + $(this).val() + '</div>');
      });

      //serialize your form data
      var toSubmit = $('input[type=text]').serialize();

      //do ajax here
      $.post('test.php', toSubmit, function(data) {
        alert('Your AJAX POST request returned: ' + data);
      }, 'text');

      //this will prevent the form from submitting normally
      return false;
   });
});
```

Here's a demo of this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/SA3XY/

Also see my comment on your question.

Comment: I'd never heard of jsfiddle before. Awesome site! Thanks for posting it here

Comment: It's been cropping up on SO a lot lately.  I just heard of it earlier this week and have been trying to use it in my js/jQuery related answers as much as possible.  It's an amazing little tool, especially considering that it's labeled as being in alpha.

Answer (score 0):

Well for the form submit you need to add the following to the form to cancel the default submit event:

```
<form onsubmit="return functioncall();">
```

Then when you return false from the function it will cancel the default form action.

EDIT: If you would like to see all the data that is to be submitted you can serialize the form using jquery `serialize()` method or `serializeArray()` method.

Comment: This solution is not ideal, as it violates the precept of Unobtrusive Javascript.

Comment: Then I get the string serialized, like a query-string. I would like the value to be displayed as exactly what is typed in the box. if you for example type "I'm a dane". then the output in some "placeholding elements", for example a <span></span> will be "I'm a dane, not "foo=weird_query&string" :)

Comment: @Ender yeah you are right. You could just change it to be attached via the submit event in jquery. Just put simple answer.

Comment: @Latze I didn't see how you wanted to present the information anywhere in the question so I just assumed you were wanting to debug something.

Comment: You are right, I did not formulate myself very well in this question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to accomplish validation, there's a much easier way, just use a validation plugin like this one:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Makes it much easier and takes the headache out of developing your own code. Jquery makes it easy to develop powerful javascript applications...but sometimes it's just easier to use stuff that's already been written and debugged (for the most part at least).